# How to update the version of pandas that I'm using in Visual Studio code. I think my python installs are setup improperly

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I've scoured the internet without much luck of finding how to fix what I'm doing wrong. I think I have all the pieces to the puzzle and know what is wrong but I just don't know what I need to do to fix it.

I'm starting to think I have two installs of python and I'm not updating the install that's being used in VS code and the python install that I have updated is not properly setup in VS code. I have anaconda downloaded but I think the VS code python extension is the only one that is set up properly. If I use the anaconda prompt and follow what a number of posts/solutions detail

```
import pandas as pd

pd.__version__
```

I get 1.1.3 which I believe I updated the other day when trying to fix my issue. However, if I use the terminal in VS code and do the same thing, I get 1.0.5 (which is the pandas version that produces the issue I am dealing with... it messes with dates when plotting pandas df). I'm guessing this has something do to with anaconda not being set to PATH and VS code is using the extension instead of the anaconda download. To further back this up, if I select
`Python 3.7.9 64-bit (conda)` interpreter instead of `Python 3.7.9 64-bit`
and run code that typically works on the non-conda interpreter, I get the following:

```
 "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.7 from "C:\Users\user
\anaconda3\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

If what I suspect is the issue, then I'm a bit confused how I've been able to import and use packages such as pandas, matplotlib, and Numpy when using the non-conda interpreter.

Would someone be able to explain and steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you checked out this documentation? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments
There can be some confusion because the Python interpreter you have selected in VS Code (very bottom left) can be different from what you are interacting with to install packages in the VS Code terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for getting two different versions of "`pandas`" is that the Python interpreter you are using is different. The "`Python 3.7.9 64-bi`t" you use is the python interpreter (global environment) that you downloaded and installed, and the "`Python 3.7.9 64-bit (conda)`" is the Python interpreter that comes with Anaconda (conda environment).

According to the terminal information you provided, there is no dependent package "`numpy`" of "`pandas`" in a non-conda environment. It is recommended that you install the module "`numpy`" (`pip install numpy`). Usually, when the module "`pandas`" is installed, the terminal will automatically install the dependencies it needs. Therefore, you could also reinstall "`pandas`" in the VSCode global environment.

If you want to specify a certain version of the module "`pandas`", you could use "`pip install pandas==1.1.3`" to install version 1.1.3.

[image]

[image]